# Maximal tori in semi-simple linear algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over an algebraically closed field. Furthermore, let $G$ be semi-simple, i.e. its radical (viz. its maximal closed, connected, solvable normal subgroup) is trivial. One step in a proof I'm trying to understand seems to use the following fact:

If $G$ is connected and non-trivial, then there is a non trivial maximal torus in $G$.

Why is that true? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a theorem of Grothendieck, even true over any base field. See SGA 3, tome II, Exp. XIV, Theorem 1.1 (it is also available in Linear algebraic groups by Borel, Theorem 18.2).

Comment: In my copy of Borels book, Theorem 18.2 only says that a connected group contains a maximal torus, but not that it is non-trivial if $G$ is non-trivial. Or am I understanding it wrong?